# Can someone explain me how to get sorl-thumbnail working on the Admin page of Django?

Tags: django, admin, sorl-thumbnail

I've got sorl-thumbnail up and running in templates with Redis to store the thumbnails. Great stuff!! However, I would like to have thumbails in my Admin. I used the example in the documentation (see below) but with no luck.

```
from gallery.models import Photo
from django.contrib import admin
from sorl.thumbnail.admin import AdminImageMixin

class PhotoAdmin(AdminImageMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(Photo, PhotoAdmin)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I do something very similar and it works for me.  However, I use a slightly different method, importing my admin from a utils/admin.py in my site base instead, allowing easy inheritance across my models with other apps such as django-reversion, django-guardian, and django-markitup.

gallery/admin.py:

```
#from django.contrib import admin
from utils import admin
from gallery.models import Photo

class PhotoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    #your customizations

admin.site.register(Photo,PhotoAdmin)
```

utils/admin.py:

```
from django.contrib.admin import *
from django.db import models
from sorl.thumbnail.admin import AdminImageMixin

class ModelAdmin(AdminImageMixin, ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

Comment: Thanx for your answer. I am going to try this

Comment: This is a nice abstraction but shouldn't be necessary to solve the problem. An answer that addresses the straightforward case (what the author is doing, and myself also running into this :) would be great.

Comment: Okay, I think I figured it out, so I added an answer below, sorry for the noise :)

Answer (score 0):

Your model's ImageFields need to be sorl's ImageField (`from sorl.thumbnail.fields import ImageField`) instead of the standard django.db.models.ImageField.

This field is a drop-in replacement, so just updating this should fix the issue, or at least it did for me. If you are using South for database migrations, note that it will generate one for this, which is fine.